# PHP Value from one page to next page

Tags: php

Page one:

```
<form action="order.php?pck=1">
 <div class="price-btn">
 <button href="order.php?pck=1" class="outline-btn">order now</button>
   </div></form>
```

Page two:

```
<h2>Your Order <?php 
            if ($_GET[pck]=='1'){
            echo 'Package 1';}
            ?> </h2>
```

How can i send value from one page to two?

Comment: Use button type and name instead of href

Comment: Like <button type="submit" name="submit" class="outline-btn">order now</button>

Comment: Then <h2>Your Order <?php 
            if (isset($_GET[submit])){
            if ($_GET[pck]=='1'){
            echo 'Package 1';}}
            ?> </h2>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data tough  anchor tag as query string

> i.e. `<a href="order.php?pck=1" class="outline-btn">order now</a>`
>
> Or second way, you can submit form `<form action="order.php?pck=1">.`

Comment: Working, Thanks :)

Comment: One more question, in page two i have:Warning: Use of undefined constant pck - assumed 'pck' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /BRD/order.php on line 62

Comment: In you if condition `if ($_GET[pck]=='1'){`, use `if ($_GET['pck']=='1'){`.